# guzzle post with headers not working

Tags: php, post, guzzle, request-headers

I need to do a post call to a web service, with "authorization" field in the header, but I always get *500 Internal Server Error* from the server.

The strange thing is if I do the same call with Postman I get the result.
I thought that my guzzle call is wrong.

This is the code:

```
$client = new Client([
    'verify' => false
]);
try {
    $res = $client->post(
        $base_uri . $uri, [
            'headers' => [
                'content-type'  => 'application/json',
                'authorization' => $login['token'],
            ],
            'form_params' => []
        ]
    );
    echo 'OK';
    return json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    echo 'ClientException';
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo 'Exception';
}
```

This catches the "Exception" exception.
I attach the image of postman call that does not get the error.

[image]

I checked:

- the uris are the same;
- the authorization parameters are the same;
- the body in postman is empty.